# I have a class with some parameters that I'd like to be filled using data from a JSON file

Tags: ruby, json

I am trying to create a monopoly manager for fun and I have the data for all the tiles in a JSON file which I'd like to use to iterate over and use for the data. I currently have this code:

```
require 'json'

file = File.read('monopoly-data.json')
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
data = data_hash['properties'].sort_by{ |e| e['id'].to_i }

class Property
  attr_accessor :id, :group, :colour, :name, :price, :rent, :house_price, :mortage

  def initialize(params = {})
    @id = params[:id]
    @group = params[:group]
    @colour = params[:colour]
    @name = params[:name]
    @price = params[:price]
    @rent = params[:rent]
    @house_price = params[:house_price]
    @mortage = params[:mortage]
  end
end
```

And the JSON file is [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/sondr3/86f4c0c23703ca4e5898#file-data-json).

I haven't been able to figure out how to use the JSON data to make more properties, I have played around with `for` loops on the data, `data.each` trying to make something like this automatically:

```
parkveien = Property.new(
  id: 1,
  group: 'property',
  colour: 'brown',
  name: 'Parkveien',
  price: 1200,
  rent: [40, 200, 600, 1800, 3200, 5000],
  house_price: 1000,
  mortage: 600
)
```

However I just can't wrap my head around how to do that, any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `each` to generate the Property objects and collect them into an array.

```
properties = []
data.each { |property| properties << Property.new(property) }
```

You can then access individual properties from the array by using `select` as needed.

```
properties.select { |property| property.name == "Parkveien" }
```

Also, since the keys in your data hash are strings, you need to change your initialize to use strings instead of symbols:

```
def initialize(params = {})
    @id = params["id"]
    @group = params["group"]
    @colour = params["colour"]
    @name = params["name"]
    @price = params["price"]
    @rent = params["rent"]
    @house_price = params["house_price"]
    @mortage = params["mortage"]
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it tomorrow when I wake up, but I really appreciate you taking your time!

Comment: Nevermind, wanted to try it before going to bed anyways and it works! Thank you, you saved me hours of headache.

Comment: The `detect` method would actually be a lot better than `select` since `detect` stops at the first block that returns true. Select will keep going until the end of the collection regardless. @SondreNilsen